# USB 3.0 docking station dual display poor performance

Tags: laptop, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I got a plugable USB 3.0 docking station in order to set up my laptop with dual monitors. The problem is, the display performance of the monitor hooked up to the docking station via an HDMI cable is significantly worse than the monitor hooked up directly to my laptop via an HDMI cable. This is especially apparent when minimizing windows, as the window will minimize in this sort of clunky slow motion.

Is the problem just that the USB 3.0 connection to the docking station is this much of a bottleneck on the display's performance? Or is there some separate issue such as drivers? And if a USB docking station isn't the ideal way to get a dual monitor setup, what is?